# Location path for my.ini file

Tags: mysql

I just installed MySQL Server 5.6 for the next time.
Before that I uninstalled all file and delete all folder of old version.

But after trying to open "OPTIONS FILE" I still get message that, system couldn't find my.ini file with PATH which I used in old installation.

So my question is where is this filepath configuration stored, if new fresh, installed MySQL is trying to find my.ini file in old locatin?

Comment: With wich OS you workk? Windows, Linux?

Comment: What OS? (Windows __?) What is the value in your PATH?

Comment: My OS is Windows.
PATH is D:\MySQLData\my.ini